# Tap to open item doesn't work in Lubuntu 20.04 RedmiBook 15

Tags: 20.04, lubuntu, touchpad, mousepad

I have installed Lubuntu 20.04 on my RedmiBook 15 and I have checked  single click to activate items, but it still doesn't work (can't tap to open item). I still need to use the touchpad's left click to open items though.

How do I fix this?

Comment: found the solution https://major.io/2021/07/18/tray-icons-in-i3/ , xinput then xinput list-props of touchpad name, and set the libinput Tapping Enabled (322) to 1

Comment: Well done on fixing the issue. Please write your solution in the ANSWER section of this thread; then in time, you can accept it as your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Run `xinput` to show the touchpad name. Then run `xinput list-props "touchpad name"` with the output touchpad name, and change the `libinput Tapping Enabled (322)` value from `0` to `1`

Start with the `xinput` command to determine which devices are on your system. If xinput isn't installed run `sudo apt install xinput` to install it.

Example output of `xinput`:

```
➜ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The touchpad is the second entry in the first group: `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad`. Now you can list all the properties of this device using the id number (12 in this case) or the full name:

```
➜ xinput list-props "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (187):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (189): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (322): 0
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (323): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (324):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (325):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (326):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (327):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (328):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (329):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (330):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (331):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (332):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (333):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (334):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (335):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (336):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (337): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (338):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (339):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (340):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (341):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (342): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (343): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (344):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (345):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (346):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (347): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (348): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (307): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (308):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (309):    0, 0
    Device Node (310):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (311):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (349):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (350):   1
```

The important line in the output is this one:

```
libinput Tapping Enabled (322): 0
```

Turn on tap-to-click for the touchpad:

```
xinput set-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

Your tap-to-click should now work. If it doesn't, go back to the list
of input devices and double check that there isn't another touchpad.
Some laptops show multiple touchpads even though there's only one in
the system. This is due to extra buttons being labeled as a touchpad
on some laptops.

<sub>**Source:** [Enable touchpad tap to click in i3](https://major.io/2021/07/18/tray-icons-in-i3/)</sub>