# tap to click / touchpad settings not consistent between restarts

Tags: touchpad, i3-wm

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and am using i3. I am using this previously-answered solution to turn on tap to click.

[Tap to open item doesn't work in Lubuntu 20.04 RedmiBook 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1387353/tap-to-open-item-doesnt-work-in-lubuntu-20-04-redmibook-15/1388572#1388572)

And I added this (with exec prepended) to my i3 config so that it should run when I restart my laptop. However, what I'm finding is that the tap to click isn't working. And when I run xinput I find that my touchpad now has a different ID number assigned to it. I bring my laptop to a second location with a different keyboard there that I plug into. Could it be that this process of having the other keyboard plugged in, or not, is changing the touchpad's ID number, and if so, how can I write a 'universal' enable tip to click command that isn't dependent on the changing xinput ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I implemented a solution by specifying the Touchpad name in my i3 config.

First I needed to find the trackpad's full specific name.

```
xinput list
```

This game me the full name of my touchpad. On my XPS-13 that name was something like *CUST0001:00 16CB:76AF Touchpad*

So I added the following line to my i3/config file:

```
exec xinput set-prop "CUST0001:00 16CB:76AF Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1
```

This line is essentially setting the property "libinput Tapping Enabled" from 0 (off) to 1 (on) for my named touchpad.